# how does destructuring in javascript work without an explicit assignment?

Tags: ecmascript-6

came across following code, just don't understand how it works even without an explicit destructuring assignment?

```
const createUser = ({ userName, avatar }) => ({
  userName,
  avatar
})

console.log(createUser({ userName : 'user1', avatar : 'avatar'}))
```

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-argument-lists-runtime-semantics-argumentlistevaluation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have indeed a destructuring here:

```
const createUser = ({ userName, avatar }) => ...
```

Because that is a shorthand for:

```
const createUser = (params) => {
    let { userName, avatar } = params;
```

Notice your function is not receiving two parameters, just one, and is destructuring it right away.